# Argument of type '10' is not assignable to parameter of type 'CanvasColumnFactor'

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, error, spfx-webparts, modern-experience

Why we cannot create a page section with the configuration of two columns with the first one filling the 2 of the 12 column of the layout and the second column filling 10 of the 12 column of layout.

When I use the code bellow:

```
const page = await ClientsidePageFromFile(sp.web.getFileByServerRelativeUrl("/sites/" + b[1] + "/SitePages/Home1.aspx"));
let section = page.addSection();
let leftColumn = section.addColumn(2);
let rightColumn = section.addColumn(10);
```

I get the message error:

> Argument of type '10' is not assignable to parameter of type 'CanvasColumnFactor'

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As per [SharePoint/PnP-JS-Core library](https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-JS-Core/blob/master/dist/pnp.d.ts), `CanvasColumnFactorType` is defined as:

```
/**
 * Column size factor. Max value is 12 (= one column), other options are 8,6,4 or 0
 */
export type CanvasColumnFactorType = 0 | 2 | 4 | 6 | 8 | 12;
```

So, you cannot pass 10 value to parameter of type `CanvasColumnFactor`. You have to use one of the above values.

---

**Additional**:

> Note that the total value of `CanvasColumnFactorType` in one section should be 12. Otherwise, you can not edit the created section on the web page.

**Source**: [spfx-add-news-button-webpart](https://github.com/MickNabewata/spfx-add-news-button-webpart)